# Spark is not using all configured memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

Starting spark in standalone client mode on 10 nodes cluster using Spark-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.
9 nodes are workers, 10th is master and driver. Each 256GB of memory.
I'm having difficuilty to utilize my cluster fully.

I'm setting up memory limit for executors and driver to 200GB using following parameters to spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --executor-memory 200g --driver-memory 200g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=200g
```

When my application starts I can see those values set as expected both in console and in spark web UI `/environment/` tab.
But when I go to `/executors/` tab then I see that my nodes got only 114.3GB storage memory assigned, see screen below.

[image]

Total memory shown here is then 1.1TB while I would expect to have 2TB. I double checked that other processes were not using the memory.
Any idea what is the source of that discrepancy? Did I miss some setting? Is it a bug in `/executors/` tab or spark engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're fully utilizing the memory, but here you are only looking at the storage portion of the memory. By default, the storage portion is 60% of the total memory.

[From Spark Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview)

> Memory usage in Spark largely falls under one of two categories: execution and storage. Execution memory refers to that used for computation in shuffles, joins, sorts and aggregations, while storage memory refers to that used for caching and propagating internal data across the cluster.

As of Spark 1.6, the execution memory and the storage memory is shared, so it's unlikely that you would need to tune the memory.fraction parameter.

If you're using yarn, the main page of the resource manager's "Memory Used" and "Memory Total" will signify the total memory usage.

[image]

Comment: Clearly explained, thanks! There should be info on that in web ui as it is currently confusing.

Comment: **@jangorecki, @David** in `Storage Memory` column of `Spark` UI shown above, the figures after slash `/` denote *total memory available for caching `RDD`s / `DataFrame`s*. As per [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management), `Spark` now has a common *memory pool* for **execution and storage**. Combining these two facts, I infer that if I allocate X `GB` memory to each `executor` (for *execution & storage*; using `spark.memory.fraction`), the entire X `GB` should show up here (figure after slash). But for me out of `15.59 GB`, only `11.9 GB` is showing up.

Comment: @y2k-shubham In reality, you're always going to require some execution memory. How much will be required, however, can't really be defined. It could be more or less depending on how much data you're working with and the tasks you are performing. I'm not sure how that number is being populated, but I'd take it with a grain of salt